# Dotnet HttpWebRequest error 401, but same address works in browser

Tags: .net

I have a strange problem with a function made for me that runs perfectly in many situations, but in an address (I can't to say for confidentiality) returns always an error 401. In a browser, this address works fine, but with HttpWebRequest don't. For more information, the server runs with SSL and SAP. The function it's the next:

```
public static HttpWebResponse MakeRequest(string uri, string method, Dictionary<string, string> postData, CookieContainer cookies, ICredentials credentials, WebProxy proxy)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.CookieContainer = (cookies != null) ? cookies : new CookieContainer();
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    webRequest.Credentials = (credentials != null) ? credentials : CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    webRequest.Method = method.ToUpper();
    webRequest.Headers.Add("HTTP_USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1134.0 Safari/537.1");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("HTTP_ACCEPT", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING", "gzip,deflate");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE", "es-ES,es;q=0.8");
    webRequest.Headers.Add("HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");

    // allows for validation of SSL conversations
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
        ValidateRemoteCertificate
    );

    if (proxy != null)
    {
        webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
    }

    if (method.ToLower() == "post" && postData != null)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string key in postData.Keys)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", key, Text.UrlEncode(postData[key].ToString()));
        }

        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            string finalString = sb.ToString();
            Text.Chop(ref finalString);
            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(finalString);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;
            Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        return (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

401 means you are having an authorization issue. Given that you are setting credentials in your request, i would guess that those are not correct. Example, it could be that the Authentication field has a more acceptable value that the one you are using in your code. One way, you could debug the problem would be to check what is in the header of the request when you make it in a browser (i.e. when it works). You can verify the header with a number of ways, namely, Firefox and Firebug addon to inspect the header or, you could use wireshark.

Comment: I correct myself: I do not need to pass credentials (not even basic) to view the page in the browser. The problem occurs whether or not having to put credentials. As I say, the page looks smooth in the browser but not in my code. Any help will be highly regarded. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you saying that the page is incorrectly rendered in your app vs. in a browser? I thought that you get 401 in your app and in browser all is fine. If the problem is with a 401, i would advise you to inspect the headers in the request made by the browser using one of the method above and duplicate that in your code. It could also be that certificates are not registered on your device or emulator. Could you try with the Internet Explorer on the device or emulator you are testing with. Otherwise, can you clarify what problem (rendering?) you are having?

Comment: In short, the problem is that I can see the page without errors in a browser (Chrome for example, without asking user and password), but my program returns a 401 error, though I should not have to identify myself to enter. I've compared headers Chrome and my code and are basically the same, so I do not understand the difference. I've also tried to set a proxy, but neither works. I lost many hours I have been on this problem and frankly I do not know where it can be the solution, so any help is welcome. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are wasting lots of time. As a last idea of the top of my head, I wonder if there is a problem with the certificates in your application. I suppose you are indiscriminately returning true in the ValidateRemoteCertificate
method as a test right? Do you know if the website you are accessing requires a client certificate?

Comment: Specifically, this web site is a corporate and indeed there is a problem with the server certificate, which is that all browsers say it is expired. Indeed, I am returning ValidateRemoteCertificate = true because if not indeed impossible to attempt to access (browsers always ask if we accept the expired certificate, but after that, allow access). When I finally got to solve this problem, is when the server has started to return a 401. And not, it don't require a client cerfiticate.

Comment: I know the context of this problem is strange, but I can not understand is because the browser can access and my code. Anyway, thank you very much for taking the time to my problem. It would be nice to find some clue about it ...

Oh, and sorry for my poor English ... :)

Comment: It is hard to debug the problem from comments. I wish you luck. If you have new input write here and i can have perhaps a new idea.

Comment: Thanks anyway ... If I can fix I will tell here. Greetings.